nextjs - initializsing masonry layout correctly with dynamic import
I'm trying to create some dashboards in nextjs - and I have started a project with masonry layout - but I can't seem to get it to initialize.
I've tried setting it in the useEffect - but its not doing anything.
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/ldpqcx
"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

export default function MasonryUI() {
  const msnry = "";

  useEffect(() => {
    const Masonry = dynamic(() => import("masonry-layout"), { ssr: false });
    var msnry = new Masonry(".grid", {
      itemSelector: ".grid-item",
      columnWidth: 200,
    });
    console.log("msnry", msnry);
  }, [msnry]);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Masonry - columnWidth</h1>

      <div className="grid">
        <div className="grid-item"></div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2"></div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--height3"></div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--width3"></div>
        <div className="grid-item"></div>
        <div className="grid-item"></div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height3"></div>
        <div className="grid-item"></div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
        <div className="grid-item"></div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2"></div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
        <div className="grid-item"></div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
        <div className="grid-item"></div>
        <div className="grid-item"></div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--height3"></div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
        <div className="grid-item"></div>
        <div className="grid-item"></div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}


this had no impact
import Masonry from "masonry-layout"; // Direct import of Masonry

export default function MasonryUI() {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      const element = document.querySelector(".grid");
      if (element) {
        const masonryInstance = new Masonry(element, {
          itemSelector: ".grid-item",
          columnWidth: 200,
        });
        console.log("masonryInstance", masonryInstance);
      }
    }
  }, []); // Not any need it's unnecessary


what is causing this failed to initialize error?

" need to add a file in the types folder, where you define the types. Just like the folder named types in the root directory of your app, create a file named masonry-layout.d.ts, and add this code: declare module 'masonry-layout';"

was  given this but this has no impact -- https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/affectionate-dijkstra-forked-mt9mzz?workspaceId=656c4878-42fe-46c4-a40a-ee67d4400114

This seems to be the solution
-- there was a class on main
-- used regular instance and import of masonry
-- created a type
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/affectionate-dijkstra-forked-kvwplk
"use client";

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Masonry from "masonry-layout"; // Direct import of Masonry

export default function MasonryUI() {
  useEffect(() => {
    var element = document.querySelector(".grid");
    if (element) {
      const masonryInstance = new Masonry(element, {
        itemSelector: ".grid-item",
        columnWidth: 200,
      });
      console.log("masonryInstance", masonryInstance);
    }
  }, []); // Removed msnry dependency as it's unnecessary

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Masonry - columnWidth</h1>

      <div className="grid" style={{ border: "2px solid black" }}>
        <div className="grid-item">Hi there</div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2">
          Hi there
        </div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--height3">Hi there</div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--height2">Hi there</div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--width3">Hi there</div>
        <div className="grid-item">Hi there</div>
        <div className="grid-item">Hi there</div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--height2">Hi there</div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height3">
          Hi there
        </div>
        <div className="grid-item">Hi there</div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--height2">Hi there</div>
        <div className="grid-item">Hi there</div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height2">
          Hi there
        </div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--width2">Hi there</div>
        <div className="grid-item">Hi there</div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--height2">Hi there</div>
        <div className="grid-item">Hi there</div>
        <div className="grid-item">Hi there</div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--height3">Neil</div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--height2">Petal</div>
        <div className="grid-item">Hello</div>
        <div className="grid-item">John</div>
        <div className="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

also creating a type
// types/masonry-layout.d.ts
declare module "masonry-layout" {
  export default class Masonry {
    constructor(element: Element, options?: MasonryOptions);
    layout(): void;
    reloadItems(): void;
    destroy(): void;
  }

  interface MasonryOptions {
    itemSelector?: string;
    columnWidth?: number | string | Element;
    gutter?: number;
    percentPosition?: boolean;
    stamp?: string;
    fitWidth?: boolean;
    originLeft?: boolean;
    originTop?: boolean;
    transitionDuration?: string;
    resize?: boolean;
    initLayout?: boolean;
  }
}


"when you use typescript you have to consciously define the types what you code inside your components or pages etc. Sometime you have to define types globally which you know share in general and sometime you only have to define inside the specific component:: Depends upon the scenario."
